# Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$created_at

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm having an issue that possibly a lot of people already had on here, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm trying to use Carbon and Paginate in the same variable, but keep getting the error shown in the title.

The code that I'm trying to use it with is:

Controller:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $announcements = Announcement::withCount('replies')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        $birthdays = User::whereRaw('DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) <= DAYOFYEAR(birthday) AND DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) + 365 >=  dayofyear(birthday)')
            ->orderByRaw('DAYOFYEAR(birthday)')
            ->get();
        $date = Carbon::create($announcements->created_at)->locale('nl');

        return view('home', compact('announcements', 'birthdays', 'date'));
    }
```

View:

```
@foreach($announcements as $announcement)
                    <div class="announcement">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-11">
                        <h2 style="font-size:1.5rem;" class="text-capitalize">{{$announcement->post_title}}</h2>
                        @if($announcement->post_image == null)
                            @else
                        <img src="{{$announcement->post_image}}" style="width:100%;">
                        @endif
                        <p style="font-size: 0.8rem;">{{$birthday->isoFormat('LL')}} | Geplaatst door <span>{{$announcement->username}}</span> | <span style="color:#007ac3">{{$announcement->replies_count}} reacties</span></p>
                        <p style="margin-top: -10px; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">{!! Str::words($announcement->post_content, 20) !!}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            @if(Auth::user()->admin == 1)
                            <a href="/mededeling/destroy/{{$announcement->id}}"><i class="fal fa-dumpster" style="text-align: center;position: relative;font-size: 20px;"></i></a>
                                @endif
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <p><a href="/mededeling/{{$announcement->slug}}">Meer lezen <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></p>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
```

I'm expecting it to translate the date to Dutch, but for now all I'm getting is the error.

Comment: the $announcement variable is Paginator variable. You have the get the first element (or select one you want) and than you can get created_at property

Answer (score 0):

The ->paginate() method returns a LengthAwarePaginator object, not a single model. You'll need to map the date function over each element in the Collection object.

Comment: And how would I do that? I'm still novice at Laravel hehe

Comment: @SpookyCode just remove the line `$date = Carbon::create($announcements->created_at)->locale('nl');` i dont see you using `$date` or `created_at` attribute in your loop. if you still need $date : `$date = Carbon::create($announcements->items[0]->created_at)->locale('nl');`

Comment: Just remove the $date line actually, inside your blade template, you can translate the date there while inside the loop:

`{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($announcement->created_at)->locale('nl')->format('your format')}}`

Comment: Thank you :) It worked, any idea how I can do this with the $birthdays variable as well??

Comment: Well, it's a collection / array. So you'll have to iterate over them to achieve the same result.